# WebAuthenticationBroker Facebook Given URL is not allowed

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a new update for my existing Windows 8.1 app (written in C#). On this update, I would like the users to connect to Facebook. I found a lot of tutorials to make this work but I still don't have a solution.

When the WebAuthenticationBroken is called I have the Facebook login page (with Facebook logo and email and password fields) but on the top I have this:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a of one of the App's domains.

When I fill my info and click on Login I got an error like this from the WebAuthenticatonBroken UI: (I'm not using my Windows in English, so I don't know how it is exactly written)

> We couldn't connect to the service right now. Check your internet connection or try again later.

My Facebook app is live, the SID is defined on the Windows Store ID field on basic settings.

Here I have my C# code used to call the WebAuthenticationBroker on my Windows 8.1 app:

```
    public Uri _callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
    public string FacebookAppId = "15911339xxxxxxxx";        
    public string FacebookPermissions = "public_profile,email,user_friends";

    FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();
        var loginUrl = _fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = FacebookAppId,
            redirect_uri = _callbackUri.AbsoluteUri,
            scope = FacebookPermissions,
            display = "popup",
            response_type = "token"
        });
    WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                  WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                  loginUrl);

                if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                var callbackUri = new Uri(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
                var facebookOAuthResult = _fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(callbackUri);

                FacebookClient fbclient = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);
                dynamic result = await fbclient.GetTaskAsync("me");
                string id = result.id;
                string email = result.email;
                string FBName = result.name;

                ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["UserID"] = id;
                var accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
            }
```

I've already tried with no Valid OAuth redirect uri and with the "https://www.facebook.com" as well, but it's still not working.
I've also tried setting the "Embedded browser OAuth Login" and the "Native or desktop app?" on.
I'm using the most recent Facebook SDK for Windows Store.

I hope someone can help me fix this error.

PS: sorry for my bad English...

Thanks,
Rafael Pedro da Silva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it :) It's working now.

I just had to set the redrect url ( "FacebookClient().GetLoginUrl()" and on the callbackUri of the WebAuthenticationBroker ) and on Facebook settings to "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html".